# How to plot a line representing a value from a dataframe with two geometry columns?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


points = gpd.GeoDataFrame([['A', Point(1.5, 1.75), Point(2, 2), 16],
                          ['B', Point(3.0,2.0), Point(3, 4), 18],
                       ['C', Point(2.5,1.25), Point(1, 1), 19]],
                    columns=['id', 'geometry', 'geometry b', 'value'], 
                    geometry='geometry')
```

the first geometry column represents the starting point, the second the ending point of a line which has a value corresponding to the value column.

I have tried to plot this with:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = [12, 12])
points.plot(ax=ax, column = 'value')
```

However it just plots the first geometry column and colours the points corresponding to their value.

How do I produce a plot that draws the lines, colour coded to their value?

Comment: if you have two points that should make a line, you should combine them into a line geometry. A **fundamental** assumption with geopandas is that there is only one column that contain the geometry and it is called "geometry"

Comment: Agree with @PaulH.  What you need to do is to make code to calculate a new column with the line geometry first.  Then assign that column as the active geometry of the geodataframe. Then plot.

Answer (score 1):

This working code and its output plot demonstrate how you can achieve what you need. See comments in the code for more details.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# handle all points and create relating lines
pA1 = Point(1.5, 1.75)
pA2 = Point(2, 2)
line_A = LineString([[pA1.x, pA1.y], [pA2.x, pA2.y]])
pB1 = Point(3.0, 2.0)
pB2 = Point(3, 4)
line_B = LineString([[pB1.x, pB1.y], [pB2.x, pB2.y]])
pC1 = Point(2.5, 1.25)
pC2 = Point(1, 1)
line_C = LineString([[pC1.x, pC1.y], [pC2.x, pC2.y]])

# create a geodataframe,
# assigning the column containing `LineString` as its geometry
pts_and_lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame([['A', pA1, pA2, 16, line_A],
            ['B', pB1, pB2, 18, line_B],
            ['C', pC1, pC2, 19, line_C]],
            columns=['id', 'beg_pt', 'end_pt', 'value', 'LineString_obj'], 
            geometry='LineString_obj')  # declare LineString (last column) as the `geometry`

# make a plot of the geodataframe obtained
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = [4, 4])
pts_and_lines.plot(ax=ax, column = 'value');
plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image]

If you prefer to build a dataframe containing `from_point` and `to_point` first, then append new column containing `LineString` creating from the existing points, here is an alternative code.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# this dataframe `points_df` contains from_point, to_point for creating `lineString`.
points_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame([['A', Point(1.5, 1.75), Point(2, 2), 16],
                          ['B', Point(3.0,2.0), Point(3, 4), 18],
                       ['C', Point(2.5,1.25), Point(1, 1), 19]],
                    columns=['id', 'geometry_a', 'geometry_b', 'value'])

# add new column, `line` to the dataframe,
# this column contains `LineString` geometry.
points_df['line'] = points_df.apply(lambda x: LineString([x['geometry_a'], x['geometry_b']]), axis=1)

# assign geometry to `points_df` using the column that has `LineString` geometry
# take the result as `target_gdf`
# `target_gdf` is now capable of plotting with matplotlib 
target_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(points_df, geometry=points_df['line'])

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = [4, 4])
target_gdf.plot(ax=ax, column = 'value');
plt.show()
```

Its output plot is the same as the previous one.